# error C3767: candidate function(s) not accessible Visual Studio 2010

Tags: struct, c++-cli

I'm getting this error:

```
error C3767: 'phys1::point::get_prev': candidate function(s) not accessible
```

Here's my code

phys.h

```
using namespace System;

namespace phys1 {

  typedef struct position{
    int x;
    int y;
  } pos;

 public ref class point{
   public:
     point(float speed, float gr);
   public:  
     pos get_prev();
   public: 
     pos get_next();
 };
}
```

phys.cpp

```
// This is the main DLL file.
#include "phys.h"

using namespace System;

namespace phys1 {
     ...
  static pos point::get_prev(){
    pos point;
    point.x=x;
    point.y=y;
    return point;
  }
    ...
}
```

Is it problem with my struct, which i try to use in library? Can i build it in another way?

Comment: Where'd `static` come from?  It isn't in the declaration inside the class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to pass values of type `pos` across an assembly boundary, it should be a public managed type.  `public value struct pos` would be most appropriate for what you're doing.

Native types aren't visible across assembly boundaries by default, and the `#pragma` that makes them visible is more of a kludge than a real solution.  Just make a proper .NET type with metadata.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing C++ syntax and C++/CLI syntax. The "struct" is a native definition (a C++ one).

To declare 'struct' you should better use the "value struct" construction.

The "not accessible" error can also be due to the 'position' being implicitly declared as 'private'.

See more about managed type declarations here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17741/C-CLI-in-Action-Declaring-CLR-types